# Deploy a simple angular website (Angular)

Tags: angular, deployment, web-hosting

Is there a specific restriction to deploying a simple angular website to a host server?
Is it possible to deploy an Angular app to any hosting server like "Hostinger" or "bluehost" with any chosen plan?

Comment: As long as you can upload files to your host, it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have run `ng b --prod` and copy over the output files into your host provider, you should be able to access the Angular website itself.

The only caveat is if you were to access a route (e.g. http://example.com/weather), the browser may attempt to load the content from the `/weather` subdirectory from your root.

In order to mitigate this, you have to configure your `.htaccess` file (Google up for some solutions).